# How to batch api calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to simulate event logger using JavaScript. Things that I am trying to achieve with the following snippet are:

1. For every api call, group click events and log once (the idea is to use something like debounce to achieve this)
2. With my code, there is a chance that multiple click events can fire, i would like to fire or send another batch after success of the first batch (not sure how to achieve this)

```js
const payload = {
  events: [],
};
class EventLogger {
  constructor(batchLimit = 1000) {
    this.timerId = "";
    this.isCallSent = false;
    this.events = payload;
    this.batches = batchLimit;
  }

  async logEvent(event, data) {
    this.events.events.push(data);
    console.log(this.events, "events");
    clearTimeout(this.timerId);

    this.timerId = setTimeout(async(event) => {
      const response = await sendRequest(this.events.events);
      this.events.events = [];
    }, 1000);
  }
}
const eventLog = new EventLogger(2);



window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  const parentElem = document.querySelector("#parent");
  parentElem.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    const targetElem = event.target;
    if (targetElem.className === "square") {
      const bgColor = targetElem.style.backgroundColor;
      const data = {
        color: bgColor,
      };
      const eventObj = {
        event: "click",
        timeStamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        url: location.hostname,
        data: data,
      };

      eventLog.logEvent("click", eventObj);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  height: 70px !important;
  width: 70px !important;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0)" class="square"></div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0)" class="square"></div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255)" class="square"></div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(128, 0, 128)" class="square"></div>
  <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255)" class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen when the batch limit is reached? I see no code that deals with that.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: When batch limit is reached, it should not make any more api calls. i did not know how to write code for this ?

Comment: Not ever? So the `push` just continues when clicks happen, the array just gets longer and longer, and nothing happens?

Comment: I think yes, so once the api calls are completed, another batch gets started and then api triggers

Comment: This could be better clarified. I am not clear on what exactly is expected to happen when the batch is full, when no more api calls are pending (yet the batch is still full), ...etc.

Comment: You have a race condition in `await sendRequest(this.events.events); this.events.events = [];`. Clear the array immediately before or after sending the request, not after you waited for the response.